# How to filter by range of dates in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am having some problems dealing with a database... I would appreciate a little help.

I want to count how many times an observation (e.g. registration car number) appears within a range of time (e.g. 90 days) in a database. For this, I have a numeric variable of the car number and the date in this format dd/mm/yyyy (the extent of the time series is clearly above 90 days). My intuition is about creating a new variable (mutate) that counts observations filtering by the variable date, but I don’t know how to introduce the time restriction. Any idea?

Let me show an example:

database

```
    id  date_dd/mm/yyyy
    1   01/01/2021
    1   01/02/2021
    1   02/02/2021
    1   03/02/2021
    1   30/12/2021
    2   05/07/2021
    2   03/03/2021
    2   04/12/2021
    2   07/07/2021
    12  01/05/2021
    8   06/07/2021
```

My main goal is to delete the observations that are repeated more than three times in 90 days. In conclusion, the resulting database would be:

```
id  date_dd/mm/yyyy
1   01/01/2021
1   01/02/2021
1   02/02/2021
1   30/12/2021
2   05/07/2021
2   03/03/2021
2   04/12/2021
2   07/07/2021
12  01/05/2021
8   06/07/2021
```

As I have explained above my idea has been to create a new variable that counts the number of times each id number is repeated in 90 days and then filter the data by deleting the observations that scores above 3 in the new variable but I don't have any idea of how to create this new variable with this time restriction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. It's hard to do more than guess what would help when we can't see any data or what you've tried

Comment: Thank you Camille. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

1. use `lubridate`s `ymd` function to get the date format
2. group by `id` and `arrange`
3. calculate the difference to the first date
4. add a row number column `row`
5. filter for your conditions!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(date_dd.mm.yyyy = dmy(date_dd.mm.yyyy)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(date_dd.mm.yyyy, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(diff = date_dd.mm.yyyy-first(date_dd.mm.yyyy)) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  filter(row <=4 | diff < 90) %>% 
  select(-diff, -row)
```

```
      id date_dd.mm.yyyy
   <int> <date>         
 1     1 2021-01-01     
 2     1 2021-02-01     
 3     1 2021-02-02     
 4     1 2021-02-03     
 5     2 2021-03-03     
 6     2 2021-07-05     
 7     2 2021-07-07     
 8     2 2021-12-04     
 9     8 2021-07-06     
10    12 2021-05-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lubridate` to convert your character string dates into `Date`. Now you can use `dplyr` to group and count the observations by `id`, then compare each the observation to the date of the previous observation with `lag()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    counter = seq_along(id), 
    within90days = ifelse(dt <= lag(dt) + 90, TRUE, FALSE)
  ) %>% 
  filter(counter <= 3 | !within90days)
```